# Huge gap between ceiling and floor above

Tags: architecture

I guess this question would belong on an architecture page if Stack had one. 
There is a 5 story building I was in recently that had fairly low ceilings (maybe about 8 feet) and a huge gap between floors (around 6 feet). Any specific reason for this design? All the pipes and electric cables could fit into a much smaller area, so it seems like either a waste of resources on making the building so tall, or they could have added more floors.

Answer (score 2):

the gap is usually referred to as a *mezzanine*. It is through the mezzanine that computer cabling is strung and distributed into the cubicles above and below it via holes drilled through the floors and ceilings. In a building intended to live through several generations of computer technology and through several revisions of its floor plan, you'll need your IT guys to spend significant amounts of time pulling wires through the mezzanine, so you proportion it to allow easy human access.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the expenses, there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to raise the ceiling.

You can safely move the ceiling to as close to cables and any plumbing as one inch. If extra height is essential for you, you can tastefully box in hard to move utilities such as plumbing P Traps. Many of the electrical circuitry and data cabling are fairly easy to lift up. Modern plastic electrical boxes are cheap and very easy to install, if need be. Potential ducting can be rerouted or changed with flat version.

As for the ceiling itself if it is drywall over wood or light steel joists you just move everything up. If it is T bars and acoustic tiles just adjust the hanging wires.

If you have old ugly recessed lights or fan in the ceiling this is the time to install new smart LED lights and new fans.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be required by a long clear span ; the depth is needed for beams or trusses. I am familiar with a building that has a clear span of 50 ft. using about 42" between ceiling and floor.

Answer (score 0):

The space that facilitates the distribution of computer cabling between the upper and lower cubicles in a building is commonly known as a [mezzanine](https://ameracking.ae/). This mezzanine is designed to accommodate the passage of wires through holes drilled in the floors and ceilings. In buildings intended to withstand multiple generations of computer technology and floor plan revisions, it is important to provide sufficient space in the mezzanine to allow easy access for IT personnel, who will spend considerable time pulling wires through it.